# Deque remove is not throwing ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, iterator, deque

The Deque class' [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) says:

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator method are fail-fast:
>   If the deque is modified at any time after the iterator is created, in
>   any way except through the iterator's own remove method, the iterator
>   will generally throw a ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the
>   face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and
>   cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at
>   an undetermined time in the future.

However, the below program behaves differently:

**[EDIT]:** I am getting error while pasting the whole code "An error occurred submitting the edit".  Whew! C'mon SO.

```
// create an empty array deque with an initial capacity
Deque deque = new ArrayDeque(8);

// use add() method to add elements in the deque
deque.add(15);
deque.add(22);
deque.add(25);
deque.add(20);

System.out.println("printing elements using iterator:");
for(Iterator itr = deque.iterator();itr.hasNext();)  {
    System.out.println(itr.next());
    deque.remove(); //deque is modifed after the iterator is created
}
```

I expected it to throw `ConcurrentModificationException`, but it simply prints the following output:

```
printing elements using iterator:
15
22
25
20
```

Any idea why?

Comment: You need to show your code if you want an answer!

Comment: Somehow SO didn't allow to paste the whole code.  Hence I pasted the code snippet above (sans import statements and class declaration, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's because you consume the first element of the iterator before removing it.  If you change your code to

```
for(Iterator itr = deque.iterator();itr.hasNext();)  {
    deque.remove(); 
    System.out.println(itr.next());
}
```

then you'll see the exception.  Your original implementation does indeed contradict the documentation.

However, looking in the implementation of ArrayDeque's iterator implementation, the next() method has this code:

```
E result = (E) elements[cursor];
// This check doesn't catch all possible comodifications,
// but does catch the ones that corrupt traversal
if (tail != fence || result == null)
    throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
```

Note the following paragraph in the [Deque's Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html):

> Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast iterators throw ConcurrentModificationException on a best-effort basis. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for its correctness: the fail-fast behavior of iterators should be used only to detect bugs.

Comment: Are you saying the code didn't follow this? `If the deque is modified at any time after the iterator is created`?

Comment: See the comment from the ArrayDeque code I posted: `// This check doesn't catch all possible comodifications, but does catch the ones that corrupt traversal`.  You're changing the deque in a manner that doesn't cause corruption.

Comment: @KrishPrabakar What the documentation is saying is you *might* get a CME, which is useful for debugging, but you're not guaranteed to.